# Printing selective cells in a matrix format

Tags: python, pandas

Want to print selective cells in a 4x3 matrix format, except df.iloc[4,3] cell all other cells should be printed.

How do i do this in Python Pandas, tried the following but its not helping

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,4], 'c':[3,4,5], 'd':[5,9,1]})
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    print '\n'
    for j in range(0,3):
        print "\t"
        print df.iloc[i,j]
```

Desired output should be

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
5 9
```

Comment: Could you please show me  your desired output?

Comment: Updated the question with desired output

Comment: Why did you post a picture? You can just write it out.

Comment: any particular reason why `df.iloc[4,3]` shouldn't be printed? Also your "desired output" is not a 4X3 matrix...

Comment: In my requirement, there is a need to block the display of iloc[4,3] cell, It is a 4x3 matrix..